# Laravel Route jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using Ajax to get and display content in a Laravel view. I'd like to know how I can access the second parameter in the URL. It's currently giving me back a random string:

```php
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    html+="<a href={{ route('showAnnouncement',"array[i].id_announcement") }}>";
}
```

When I alert `array{i].id_announcement` I get its value, but it doesn't pass in the URL.

Thank you!

Comment: Try @array[i].id_announcement . Documentation here : https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#defining-a-layout

Comment: @Shim-Sao : I tried it still the same..

Comment: And like this @{{... . In Blade & JavaScript Frameworks section.

Comment: are you using this code in blade or in controller ?

Comment: Saurabh Mistry in the blade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys finally I found a solution and it worked like a charm

```
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
var url = '{{ route("showAnnouncement", ":id") }}';
url = url.replace(':id', array[i].id_announcement);
    html+="<a href='"+url+"'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a JS value inside a php code.

> {{route('showAnnouncement',"array[i].id_announcement") }}

This not possible, If you are making ajax request you try something like this below.

```
var an_id = array[i].id_announcement;

$.ajax({
    url: '{{route('showAnnouncement')}}',
    data: {'an_id':an_id },
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (result)
    {
    }
 });
```

Route

```
Route::post('showAnnouncement/{an_id?}', ['as' => 'showAnnouncement', 'uses' => 'YourController@showAnnouncement']);
```